# How to call a rake task programmatically - With arguments

Tags: rake

I know we can run a task from within a rakefile like this:

```
Rake::Task['my_task'].execute()
```

How to do the same while passing arguments ?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have the following task:

```ruby
task :delete_user, [:name] do |t, args|
  puts "#{args.name} is being deleted."
end
```

You can call it using

```ruby
Rake::Task['delete_user'].invoke('john')
```

or

```ruby
Rake::Task['delete_user'].execute(Rake::TaskArguments.new([:name], ['john']))
```